# Target class not found - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return 'INDEX';
    }
}
```

and this is my route

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');

Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('pages.about');
});
```

the result is

*Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException*

*Target class [PagesController] does not exist.*

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `'PagesController@index'` doesn't contain namespace information. Does it work if you add `use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;` and replace it with `[PagesController::class, 'index']`?

Comment: Thank you very much man. Tried a bunch of other stuff found on internet but this is the first one that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `PagesController.php` file is in `App\Http\Controllers`

and Run

`composer dump-autoload`

for laravel8 route need to change with

`Route::get('/', [PagesController::class, 'index']);`

Comment: Ran it but nothing changed.

Comment: can you try with `php artisan route:list`. is it return with any errors ?
and  what version of laravel you use ?